# unbounded operator satisfying $||T(x_n)|| \to \infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $E,F$ be a normed space, and
$T:D(T) (\subset E) \rightarrow F$
be a densely defined unbounded linear operator.

By unbounedness,
for all $x \in E$, there is a sequence $(x_n) \subset D(T)$ such that
$x_n \to x$ and $||T(x_n)|| \to \infty$.

On the other hand, the follwing hold?

If $D(T) \neq E$,
there is a $x \in E$ such that
if $(x_n) \subset D(T)$ satisfy
$x_n \to x$, then $||T(x_n)|| \to \infty$.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No, take some unbounded linear operator with $D(T) = E$ and take $x_n = x$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $x_n \to x$ but $||Tx_n|| = ||Tx|| \to ||Tx|| < \infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.What about the case $x \in E \backslash D(T)$?

Comment: Well $E \setminus D(T)  = \emptyset$, so there is no such $x$.

Comment: What about the case $D(T) \neq E$?